# How to build Objects for class that has fields annotated with @XmlAnyElement and takes list of Objects

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a class like this:

```
XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "",
    propOrder = {"any"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "DynamicDataRoot"
)
public class Data {
    @XmlAnyElement(
        lax = true
    )
    protected List<Object> listOfObject;

    public MergeData() {
    }

    public List<Object> getAny() {
        if(this.any == null) {
            this.any = new ArrayList();
        }

        return this.any;
    }
}
```

I need to create object **Data** and add **list of object**s 
how to add **dynamic Jaxb Element Nodes** into this list?